# Why my IntelliJ plugin not showing in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, plugins, intellij-plugin

I just developed JSON Parser plugin for IntelliJ platform. And I published it on JetBrains.

While I am searching in the plugin repositories in Android Studio, I can't find my plugin. But it is shown in IntelliJ community edition(I am currently using it).

Below is my `plugin.xml`

```
<idea-plugin>
<id>com.godwin.json.parser</id>
<name>Json Parser</name>
<version>1.0</version>
<vendor email="godwinjoseph.k.com">Godwin</vendor>

<description><![CDATA[
  Simple JSON Parser is an IntelliJ IDE plugin for validation and formatting JSON string<br>
]]></description>

<change-notes><![CDATA[
  <h2>Version 1.0</h1>
  Parse VALID JSON string only.
]]>
</change-notes>

<!-- please see http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started/build_number_ranges.html for description -->
<idea-version since-build="173.0"/>

<!-- please see http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started/plugin_compatibility.html
     on how to target different products -->
<!-- uncomment to enable plugin in all products
<depends>com.intellij.modules.lang</depends>
-->


<extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">
    <!-- Add your extensions here -->
    <toolWindow id="Json Parser" anchor="right"
                factoryClass="com.jsonparse.ParserToolWindowFactory"/>
</extensions>

<project-components>
    <component>
        <implementation-class>com.jsonparse.ParserComponent</implementation-class>
    </component>
</project-components>
```

> But it is working fine in Android studio If I manually installed(Install from local)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the comments of the `plugin.xml` you've posted and on the [update page](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10650-json-parser/update/45225) of the plugin you have uploaded, the plugin is assumed only compatible with IntelliJ IDEA because it does not have any dependencies specified. You need to uncomment the `<depends>` tag in your plugin.xml and reupload the plugin.

If your plugin depends on Java-related IDE functionality and you want it to be available only in IntelliJ IDEA and Android Studio, use the following `depends` tag instead:

```
<depends>com.intellij.modules.java</depends>
```